# How to establish association between a Devise model and a model I have made?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, devise

How do you use User(devise which store email and password) to belong_to Profile and Profile has_one User? When I looked up the database profile_int is still nil hmmm... not sure where did I do wrong?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
 # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
 # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

 # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :profile_id
 # attr_accessible :title, :body

  belongs_to :profile
end


class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :dob, :firstName, :lastName, :school_id, :schYear, :user_attributes


 belongs_to :school
 has_one :user
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

end
```

I know usually I should do something like this Profile.create(.......) but I am not sure where to do this if I am doing it with a devise

Answer (score 0):

Should `:schoolstrong text` be ':schoolstrong_text'?  Did you run `rake db:migrate` ?

Also, checking your schema could be helpful too.

Comment: Oh my bad that is a typo... it's just "school" but the main problem still persist, i am not sure how to associate these two model in a has_one and belongs_to relation

Comment: looks like you set it up correctly though, did you try running another migration?

Comment: Yes I did. It did nothing... I am just wondering since User is created by gem file "devise" so how can I access its controller file so that I can profile.create(.....User: ....)

Comment: If you want to customize a devise controller you have to create a new controller inheriting from devise: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Tool:-Generate-and-customize-controllers.  Otherwise users will be created through completed devise's registration forms in the views.  You can customize those views but have to import them first with a rails generate devise:views

Answer (score 0):

A common practice in associating a Devise `User` with a `Profile` model is making the profile the child of the user:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :profile
end

# app/models/profile.rb
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Then, within your `User` model, you'd create an `after_create` hook to create a new `Profile` model and associate it with the newly created user:

```
# app/models/user.rb
after_create :create_profile

def create_profile
    profile = Profile.create
    self.profile = profile
    self.save
end
```